# Return error while trying to compile fftw

Tags: c++, fftw

It is a newbie in C++ question. I am trying to apply FFT to complex 1D data using FFTW.

```
 # include <stdlib.h>
 # include <stdio.h>
 # include <time.h>
 #include  <fftw3.h>

 int main(void)
 {
 int i;
 int N=100;
 fftw_complex *in;
 fftw_complex *out;
  fftw_plan plan_forward;
 unsigned int seed = 123456789; 
 in= (fftw_complex*) fftw_malloc(sizeof(fftw_complex)*N);
 out= (fftw_complex*) fftw_malloc(sizeof(fftw_complex)*N);
 srand ( seed );

   for ( i = 0; i < N; i++ )
   {
   in[i][0] = rand ( );
   in[i][1] = rand ( );
   }

   plan_forward = fftw_plan_dft_1d ( N, in, out, FFTW_FORWARD,   FFTW_ESTIMATE );

   fftw_execute ( plan_forward );

    for ( i = 0; i < N; i++ )
   {
     printf ( "  %3d  %12f  %12f\n", i, out[i][0], out[i][1] );
   }
        fftw_destroy_plan ( plan_forward );
        fftw_free ( in );

        fftw_free ( out );
         return;
   }
```

After compiling I am getting this error:

error: return-statement with no value, in function returning ‘int’ [-fpermissive]
   return;

I have no idea how to fix this error. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be

```
int N=100;
```

(note the `;` in place of the `,`)

And `ffftw_malloc` should probably be `fftw_malloc` (one `f` removed at the beginning).

Also, the compiler should probably give you line numbers for the errors, I'd suggest going to those lines and examining them closely, so you can learn to do the debugging yourself ;)

Finally, `main` returns an int, so the return statement needs a value.  (`0` should be fine.)  **Note:** the `main` function is special in that it has an implicit `return 0;` at the end, so it is the only function with a return value where you are allowed to "fall off the end".  But if you use a return statement in `main` you have to provide a value.

Comment: Thanks, I fixed that but I am still getting  error: ‘ffftw_malloc’ was not declared in this scope
 in= (fftw_complex*) ffftw_malloc(sizeof(fftw_complex)*N);

Comment: OK thank you, it is embarrassing, they were all typos !! but what about rror: return-statement with no value, in function returning ‘int’ [-fpermissive]
   return;
error?

Answer (score 1):

The error message is pretty much self-explanatory - you need to change:

```
return;
```

to:

```
return 0;
```

The reason for this is that `main` returns an `int`, so you need a value here, i.e. you can't just return "nothing".